# Are these resistors in parallel

Tags: resistors, parallel

There are 2 groups of resistors that look like they might be parallel, but in between them that's making me question if they actually are. The circuit looks like this:

[image]

If they are considered parallel, how would I take into account the resistor in between them?

Comment: All the answers are good, just remember: when nothing seems to work stick to the basics. Definition of parallel: same voltage across. Definition of series: same current through.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same circuit drawn differently.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnMdmA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Additional ways to think about the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE227V.png)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are in parallel. Just try redrawing it so that  both series legs have vertical resistors.

In effect, there is 30 ohms in parallel with 60 ohms.

Answer (score 2):

That circuit has series and parallel resistors.
The answer to the circuit equivalent resistor is :
R=((25+5)//(50+10))+5

Where:
// means parallel
+ means series

Answer (score 1):

The 10 and 50 pair is in parallel with the 25 and 5 pair. You could put the 25 resistor just above the 5. The important thing to retain is "Do not mess with the intersections"!